# Wi-Fi keeps changing between APs frequently

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04, network-manager

Right on the tin.

At home, there's a couple APs under the same SSID that are used to cover places in the house that get terrible signal and this works well in most situations. However for my laptop, running Ubuntu 20.04, I could stand to one of the APs and it'd still aggressively switch between them even though it doesn't make sense to.

This also shows itself to be an issue at the university I (used to, ahem) visit where it'd switch between the many APs regardless if I stand in the same place or move.

This becomes a problem with a few programs that get fussy if the network conditions are not stable, makes the network pointlessly sluggish whenever it's handing-over, choose an AP **away** from where I'm traveling with my laptop, or fail all-together.

Is there any way to tweak how aggressive the AP switching is? Personally I'd like it to keep on the same AP until there's enough of a signal difference or connectivity is poor enough to find a new AP to use instead of the near constant switching it's doing right now.

Comment: See also: [Super User: How can I control switching between wireless APs on Linux?](https://superuser.com/q/441400/425838)

Answer (score 1):

If you set `wifi.bssid` in NetworkManager's connection profile, then you lock the connection to a certain access point and prevent roaming.

Otherwise, roaming is enabled. How that happens exactly is not configurable, because it just must work reasonably (without configuring it).

If it does not work well for you, then there might be a bug or something that should be improved. Note that roaming decisions are made by `wpa_supplicant`. So you need to look at the debug logs of supplicant, see how/why it roams, and suggest how it should do it differently (and find out why the chosen approach is not working well for you). Without details about what is happening, it is now clear what supplicant (or NetworkManager) could improve.

Comment: I launched `wpa_supplicant` in debug and sat around to watch the input. I also monitored the scans with `nmcli` and made the determination that `wpa_supplicant` is acting appropriately with the information it's finding.

Comment: Ack! Didn't expect `Enter` to immediately post! Anyways. It looks like my laptop will hang onto one of the inferior APs, but comparing the potential throughput gain isn't worth it to switch and `wpa_supplicant` stays on it. This is a fine resolution. But watching the scans I've seen one of the APs jump to full strength then two seconds later switch to it's previous signal value. I guess there's some weird signal interference.

Answer (score 0):

Lousy work-around: hard-wire to the network.

---

Details:

I have this problem on my Dell Precision 5570 laptop running Ubuntu 22.04.

I lose internet connectivity about 10 times per hour for about 10 seconds each time. It interrupts my work. I talked to the network administrator and he said that it's because my system is switching between two Access Points (APs) very often.

I think it's because my WiFi card is so strong that it's able to pick up even weak access points that older WiFi cards wouldn't have been able to pick up, so it's getting confused somehow.

`iwconfig` shows that my network adapter, `wlp0s20f3`, has a connection strength of `-78` db.

I was unable to find a solution in my WiFi settings, so I **hard-wired to the network instead.**

I hope there exists a better solution than this.